# log off using task manager and .bat file on Windows 7 Pro

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, shutdown, taskmanager, logoff

I have Windows 7 Professional.
I wrote a file called spegnimento.bat with the following content:

case 1: `shutdown /f`

case 2: `shutdown -f`

case 3: `shutdown /s`

case 4: `shutdown /l`

If I save the file, close it, and then click it, I have the following results:

1) all files and programs are closed, then I'm logged off from Windows

2) same as 1)

3) all files and programs are closed, then the pc is shut down

4) same as 1)

However, if I ask the task manager to open the spegnimento.bat files at 6.35 pm, at that time I obtain the following results:

1) none

2) same as 1)

3) warning: the pc will be shut down in a minute. Then all files and programs are closed, and the pc is shut down

4) same as 1)

**Question (a)**:
Why do my clicks and the task manager have different results with same .bat files?

**Question (b)**:
What should I write in the .bat file so that the task manager at 6.35 pm opens it, then all files and programs are closed, and I am logged out of Windows (but the pc is not shut down)?

Comment: @user3664452 I've never really played with the task scheduler, but what I suspect is happening is that it is effectively creating a new session at 6.35, and it is _that_ session (and not your interactive one) that is being logged-off. Don't know if there's a way round that or not, but it might give you something to search on.

Comment: If you have sufficient rights, then shutdown works because it logs off everyone and shuts down.  Logoff does NOT work because shutdown.exe does not have a way to log off a *different* user -- it logs off the *current* user.  You might be able to get it to work using the task scheduler's "Run only when user is logged on" setting.  Of course, **if** that works it will only work for one user.  You would need a task for every user you want it to happen with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @avery_larry.

I used the task scheduler's "Run only when user is logged on" setting, and it **worked**.

Question "b" has been satisfactorily answered, at it suffices. Thanks to @Gerhard Barnard and @Mofi for the [superuser](https://superuser.com) suggestion

Comment: Please delete this answer as it is not really an answer, The reason why your question is not answered is because your question is off topic and should be posted on [superuser](http://superuser.com)